# Why does it keep saying syntax error when I try to run in cmd and python?

Tags: python

It keeps saying 'syntax error'.

```
import datetime
import calendar

def findDay(date):
    born = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, %d %m %y)
    day = born.weekday()
    return (calendar.day_name[day])

date = '01 01 1989'
print(findDay(date))
```

[error shown in cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkbSM.png)

Comment: Show the full error message as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: Please provide the entire error output.

Comment: You need quotes around the date format on this line: `born = datetime.datetime.strptime(date,"%d %m %y")`

Comment: Hi. Welcome to StackOverflow! These forums typically prefer a minimal example of the problem.
Your problem here is the lack of quotation marks around "%d %m %y".

You can refer to policy here on how to create a minimal example.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Don't be discouraged by the downvotes, not everyone is nice to new users. There is an expectation you will research the method (sweat equity) a little bit.  strptime() examples clearly show the 2nd parameter is a string, and you will see quotes used in those examples. This can indicate you are learning Python without having a C background.  Note the answer that exists now, does not add you could shorten the year value to make %y match. But you really need to work this out yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose `%d...` in double quotes and set %y to %Y:

```
import datetime
import calendar

def findDay(date):
    born = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%d %m %Y")
    day = born.weekday()
    return (calendar.day_name[day])

date = '01 01 1989'
print(findDay(date))
```